# What popular software takes advantage of General Purpose GPUs?

Tags: gpu, gpgpu

So I hear a lot about software development moving to GPUs.. but does anyone know of any popular software that actually leverages computations on the GPU?

Comment: MATLAB via Jacket, http://www.accelereyes.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are a couple relevant links:

- http://gpgpu.org/category/business
- http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_apps_flash_new.html#

I assume you are talking about non-graphical applications -- of course almost all modern games use the GPU in some way or another, as do graphics editors and video editing software.

That said, I don't think there's a single non-graphical "killer app" for GPU in wide consumer use yet, although there's great success in niche applications such as cryptography.